# Topology & Continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

True or false.

There exists a non empty topological space $X$, such that every function from $X$ to $Y$, where $Y$ is a nonempty topological space is continuous on $X$.

I'm not too sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: what you had tried ??

Answer (score 2):

True. Let $X$ be any non-empty set with the discrete topology, and let $Y$ be any non-empty topological space.

Comment: Thanks. That was part of my intuition but I wasn't sure if Y would be open.

Comment: The whole set $Y$ is open in its *own* topology. This is part of the definition of a topology and is therefore true for every topological space.

Answer (score 1):

If $X=\{x\}$ is a one point space, the every map $X\to Y$ is constant, hence continuous.